# Generar columnas en el Canvas.-

Tags: javascript

Tengo este programa que hace que salgan bolas arriba y caigan por el canvas, pero me gustaria que no se montaran lateralmente unas con otras, es decir, que se crearan columnas Canvas.width/Radio.  Gracias.

No se como añadir el codigo, me da un error, dice que mi consulta es casi toda código y que tengo que añadir más información.

```js
    class Matrix {
        constructor () {
            this.PosicionHorizontal = (Math.random () * Canvas.width);
            this.PosicionVertical = 0;
            this.DireccionVertical = (Math.random () * 3) + 1.5;
            this.Color = "rgba(0, 255, 0, 0.9)";
            this.Letra = Caracteres.charAt (Math.floor (Math.random () * Caracteres.length));
        }
        
        Dibujar () {
            Contexto.beginPath ();
            this.Letra = Caracteres.charAt (Math.floor (Math.random () * Caracteres.length));
            Contexto.font = "15px Arial";
            Contexto.textAlign = "center";
            Contexto.fillStyle = this.Color;
            Contexto.fillText (this.Letra, this.PosicionHorizontal, this.PosicionVertical);
        }
        
        Actualizar () {
            this.PosicionVertical = this.PosicionVertical + this.DireccionVertical;
            if (this.PosicionVertical > Canvas.height) {
                this.PosicionVertical = 0;
                this.PosicionHorizontal = (Math.random () * Canvas.width);
                this.Letra = Caracteres.charAt (Math.floor (Math.random () * Caracteres.length));
                this.DireccionVertical = (Math.random () * 3) + 1.5;
            }
            this.Dibujar ();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Te da un error porque estarás intentando añadir docenas de líneas de código para tres líneas de explicación que has puesto. Las preguntas que buscan ayuda con la depuración deben incluir un [mre], y no todo el código de tu proyecto.

Comment: Muchas gracias, voy a intentar resumir el codigo, muchas gracias.

Comment: Correcto, he puesto menos código y me ha dejado sin problemas, espero que se entienda lo que quiero decir, me gustaria que se crearan columnas en el canvas, dividiendo el ancho de este por el tamaño de la letra y asi que cayeran unas al lado de las otras sin montarse lateralmente.